# Nginx: 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: php, nginx, websocket, server

My nginx.conf file looks like this:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {

    include mime.types;
    server_tokens off;
    root /var/www/html;

    fastcgi_cache_path /tmp/nginx/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=phpcache:100m inactive=60m;
    fastcgi_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri";

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        server_name localhost;

        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+3DES:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5;

        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" always;

        index index.php index.html;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location ~\.php {
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_cache phpcache;
            fastcgi_cache_valid 200 301 302 60m;
            add_header X-FastCGI-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
            fastcgi_cache_bypass $skip_cache;
            fastcgi_no_cache $skip_cache;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, while opening *some urls*, it is throwing **502 Bad Gateway**, but not for others. The error I'm getting in error.log is:

> 2019/01/10 23:53:39 [error] 12139#12139: *5 recv() failed (104:
>   Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream,
>   client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /wordpress/
>   HTTP/2.0", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock:", host:
>   "localhost"

Please let me know what can  be the problem.

Comment: Whats in your FPM logs?

Comment: @CodyCaughlan `[11-Jan-2019 00:35:53] WARNING: [pool www] child 12467 exited on signal 11 (SIGSEGV - core dumped) after 2189.642323 seconds from start
[11-Jan-2019 00:35:53] NOTICE: [pool www] child 14303 started
[11-Jan-2019 00:35:53] WARNING: [pool www] child 13689 exited on signal 11 (SIGSEGV - core dumped) after 684.578509 seconds from start
[11-Jan-2019 00:35:53] NOTICE: [pool www] child 14305 started`

Comment: FPM is crashing; hence the core dump. Unclear *why* though. Maybe running out of memory? can you increase the FPM log verbosity to get more info?

Comment: There is nothing else in FPM log. I changed log level to notice and yet it's showing this only.

Comment: @CodyCaughlan Small php files are running fine e.g. simple `echo 'hi'` is working. But as soon as I request something heavy like wordpress or any other CMS it throws 502 error.

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs if PHP is unable to log the session information in the file. Check the session_save_path in the php.ini file.

Comment: by default session will store in /var/lib/php/sessions, Also check the ownership of the dir.